# Why Form enctype used for?

Tags: html, forms

What is the attribute enctype used for with a form?

```
<form id='injectFormUpload' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='' method='post'>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's used to specify the content type used for the request. There are 2 content types used in html forms: [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) which is the default and [`multipart/form-data`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) which is used if the form contains file inputs for uploading files. It indicates the browser how to send the request to the server. For example:

```
<form id="injectFormUpload" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="foo" value="bar" />
    <input type="text" name="foo2" value="baz" />
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>
```

when submitted will send the following POST request to the server:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Content-Length: 16
Connection: keep-alive

foo=bar&foo2=baz
```

whereas the following form which contains a file upload field:

```
<form id="injectFormUpload" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="foo" value="bar" />
    <input type="file" name="myfile" />
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>
```

might generate the following request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------265001916915724
Content-Length: 326
Connection: keep-alive

-----------------------------265001916915724 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foo" 

bar 
-----------------------------265001916915724 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myfile"; filename="test.txt" 
Content-Type: text/plain 

contents of the text file
-----------------------------265001916915724--
```